# How to make Whitespace optional in Regex

Tags: jquery

I have a regex which validate UK post code. I want it to make white space optional. How can I do it?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("postcodeUK", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i.test(value);
    }, "Please specify a valid Postcode");
```

Comment: Can you show some examples? I live in the US, and I can't tell what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?` after the space.

Tested with `AA99 9AA` and `AA999AA`

```
[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-_Ozbdi4fCtm1OyT)

Answer (score 0):

To allow arbitrary whitespace:

```
/[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i.test(value.replace(/ /g,''))
```